# Applying replacement rules to Julia expressions

Tags: pattern-matching, julia

Suppose I have a Julia expression of the form `:((x + y) + z + (u * v))`. I want to find a replacement rule which will turn this expression into `:(x + y + z + (u * v))`. I've been looking at Match.jl and Macrotools.jl but I don't see a good way to do this.

Ideally I'd like to be able to just type something like

`@match begin
    :+(_..., +(stuff...), _...) => +(_..., stuff, _...)
end`

Any pointers on how to go about doing this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The way to do it is to traverse the code and look for brackets and then jump one level to see if the operation inside the bracket is of same precedence as (or higher than)outside; if it is then remove the bracket. Not sure if there are solutions already; but can check out this for example of how to traverse.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46944224/how-to-automatically-parenthesize-an-arbitrary-julia-expression/46947012#46947012

Comment: Will take the 100 bounty :)